# WebSQL, inserting into two or more tables

Tags: database, html, web-sql

I'm using webSql, and I kind of figured everything out, except for this little thing: let's say we have two tables (A and B) and firstly, I'd like to insert in to table A and get the latest ID, which I'll insert into table B as a secundary key. In both cases, tables have auto increment ID.

when I "alert(TableAId)" from the bottom example, I get the right value. However, when I insert it into TableB, it's empty. I think the problem might be that function(tx, results) is asynchronous and thus I insert into TableB before I actually get TableAId.

What would be the appropriate solution here?

```
var TableAId = "";
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO TableA (value) VALUES (?)', [myValue], 
    function(tx, results) {
        TableAId = results.insertId;
    }, errorCB);

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO TableB (key_from_TableA) VALUES (?)', [TableAId], 
    function(tx, results) {
        TableBId = results.insertId;
    }, errorCB);
```

Comment: Isn't WebSQL deprecated?

Comment: it's still very much active in phonegap (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage) but thanks for the reply.

Comment: I'm not sure how phonegap implements it under the covers, but the spec is very clear on this http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/ Maybe you should consider IndexedDB?

Answer (score 1):

Since it is asynchronous, you will have to wait for the first operation to finish before invoking second operation.

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO TableA (value) VALUES (?)', [myValue], 
    function(tx, results) {
        var TableAId = results.insertId;
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO TableB (key_from_TableA) VALUES (?)', [TableAId], 
             function(tx, results) {
                TableBId = results.insertId;
             }, errorCB);
    }, errorCB);
```